# Most efficient way to parse slightly different format date/time strings

Tags: java, android, json, datetime

I'm parsing JSON from a server, and in it uses some *similar* but not the same formats for dates, some look like:

```
2013-12-13T09:59:59Z
```

which I can parse using

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

while others look like

```
2013/11/14 11:00:14 -0500
```

which I can parse using

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ")
```

Is there a more generic way to do this? It would obviously be better if there was a standard approach server-side, but I'm not in a position to change that.

Comment: By "generic" you mean something that would guess what the format is? I doubt it.

Comment: It is error prone to guess format of date. For instance, what is format for "07/08/2014"?
Either server should send in a fixed format OR it should send a format along.

Comment: I'm not after a completely generic way of getting for format, I'm looking for a better approach to handling the two formats above, where one uses a 'T' and one uses a space to separate the date and the time, and one uses Z to indicate 'zulu time' where the other explicitly specifies the time zone.

Comment: I believe it's incorrect to use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` to parse `2013-12-13T09:59:59Z`.  The `Z` after the time is intended to indicate that this time is UTC, but your date format ignores the `Z`, and gives you a date according to the default locale.

Comment: http://darthanthony.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/java-date-parsing-with-an-unknown-format/

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks for the first insightful comment. The docs for SimpleDateFormat on developer.android.com have Z/ZZ/ZZZ:-0800 so what's the correct format to parse the Z character itself?

Comment: You need to use a capital `X`, without any single quotes, to parse the `Z`.  So `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"` should do the trick.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, rather two XX, but OPs problem is that he uses Android where X is not supported.

Comment: In standard Java, a single X works - you only need two Xs to parse minutes.  And I think the question is ambiguous as to whether the parsing is being done on the server, or in the Android code.  Perhaps OP could clarify.

Comment: @DavidWallace The question says as first sentence: "I'm parsing JSON from a server", so it is not ON the server, but FROM the server (ON Android). Just my interpretation.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the most reasonable interpretation.  But maybe the OP could clarify anyway.  I've certainly worked on systems where one server parses data that comes from another server, before returning it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have TWO variations in formatting you could use this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX");
SimpleDateFormat other = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss XX");

String input = "2013/11/14 11:00:14 -0500";
Date result;

if (input.indexOf('/') != -1) { // or: input.charAt(4) == '/'
  result = other.parse(input);
} else {
  result = iso.parse(input);
}
```

Attention: For Android you have to use ZZ instead of XX, but I am not sure if ZZ on Android can parse the Z-symbol in ISO-inputs correctly. In case of doubt (testing!) you have another format variation which you have to handle in a specific way (using something like `input.endsWith("Z")`).

Comment: I did consider this approach, it's certainly better than just calling parse on a bunch of different DateFormats, but I was *hoping* that there'd be something that just seemed neater.

Comment: @JonathanCaryl Yes, it was my goal to try to avoid excessive parsing and catching parse errors. Unfortunately you are in bad luck to have different formats. SimpleDateFormat does not support multiple format parsing out of the box, and I doubt if a possible out-of-the-box-solution does it better internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.
Your dateFormats should not be ambigious e.g. "07/08/2013" can be "dd/MM/YYYY" or "MM/dd/YYYY".

```
private static Date parseDate(String dateString, DateFormat... dateFormats)
{
    Date date = null;

    for (DateFormat df : dateFormats)
    {
        try
        {
            date = df.parse(dateString);
            break;
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // Ignore. Try next date format
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: As parsing dates isn't the fastest operation this could be very slow. It's also making no use of the fact that the two formats I'm trying to parse are very similar: the dateFormats above could all be completely different.

Comment: Agree. I missed the "efficient" part, focused more on generic code for all formats.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is better to keep all the date formats that are likely to appear in an array, then by using a foreach loop you can check which format is best suited and You can parse it that way.
I used the following code to achieve it,

```
public static String postedTimeFormat(String inPostedTime) {

        String[] formats = {
                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", 
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", 
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", 
                "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ", 
                "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss",
                "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"};

        if (inPostedTime != null) {
            for (String format : formats) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
                try {
                    sdf.parse(inPostedTime);
                    return format;

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It'll be slow ya but by calling the function only once while parsing the json for the first time like say in utility class and not each time  you can get good results.

Comment: Jonathan, what makes you think it's going to be slow?  I can't see why it would be slow.

Comment: I mis-read the code & thought it was trying all the formats like in the answer by @Sangharsh . I guess this is a reasonable approach to finding the appropriate format.

Comment: I think @Sangharsh's answer is equivalent to this one.  You said under that answer "this could be very slow", but I don't see any evidence of that.

Comment: @JonathanCaryl @DavidWallace The code is slower because it works by catching excpetions (if first tried format does not fit). Reusing an object of `ParsePosition` instead of try-catch might improve performance, however.

Comment: Indeed, if I had format1 and format2 and I called parseDate(dateString, format1, format2) on a whole bunch of different dateStrings, all of which were format2 then every time I'd try format1, catch the ParseException and try format2. If you were using that approach you'd at least want to wrap it in something that would remember the last successful format used, and try that first when parsing the next date.

Answer (score 0):

Normalise your dates to one format, by doing something like this.

- Replace all `/` characters with `-`.
- Replace the first space character with `T`.
- Replace any subsequent space characters with empty string.

Once you've done that, you should be able to parse the resulting string with

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"
```

If you're doing this in Android code, you'll need one more step:

- Replace any Z with +00:00

and you'll need to parse with

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Comment: FWIW, I consider it a bug in Android, that they've made a class called `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, which differs from the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` provided in the standard JDK.  They should have called it `android.text.SimpleDateFormat` or something like that.  Or better still, just package the REAL `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` with Android.

Comment: No, it is not a bug because: Android != Java. You have a bug if the real implementation behaviour contradicts to specification. Here we have Android specification so from Googles perspective all is right, although they indeed imitate java class names (annoying Oracle/Sun).